# Optimization of a recursive function

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, recursion

Optimization of a recursive function

Hello everybody, I’m doing a npuzzle solver and I have a mistake…

When heuristic Manhattan is off I check all ways with the default order (top, bottom, left, right). When Manhattan is on I chose the smallest distance between all ways possible.

Example:

```
ways[ 0].way =     Top .weight manhattan =  14
ways[ 1].way =    left .weight manhattan =  16
ways[ 2].way =  Botton .weight manhattan =  2147483647
ways[ 3].way =   right .weight manhattan =  2147483647 
weight manhattan =  15
   1   7   8
   4   2   0
   5   3   6
```

Actually, the Manhattan distance is 15. If the `0` go to the top the Manhattan distance will be 14 and 16 if `0` go to the left.

I think this part is ok

My mistake is here, in the function `general_weight`. (This function is call for each node). The difference is in this piece of code when Manhattan is on. If Manhattan distance is off `grid->flag` ==  0 else `grid->flag` == `0x1u`.

```
static int          general_weight(t_grid *grid, int const flag,
        int const y_zero, int const x_zero, int const y_new, int const x_new,
        int weight)
{
    int                     y;
    int                     x;
    int                     ret;
    int                     ret1;
    int                     ret2;

    if (grid->flag == 0)
        return (flag);
    if (get_coord_value(grid->grid[y_new][x_new], grid->x_y, &y, &x) <= 0)
        return (INT_MIN);
    ret1 = (y > y_zero) ? y - y_zero : y_zero - y;
    ret2 = (x > x_zero) ? x - x_zero : x_zero - x;
    ret = weight;
    if ((grid->flag & F_MANHATTAN) != 0)
    {
        ret += ret1 + ret2;
        ret -= (y > y_new) ? y - y_new : y_new - y;
        ret -= (x > x_new) ? x - x_new : x_new - x;
    }
    ...
    return (ret);
}
```

I don’t understand how the time can be different like this. When Manhattan is on `1.45`… second to solve the grid and when it’s off `1.01` second …

Have you go an idea where the problem can from?

I don't this it's from `get_coord_value`:

```
int                         get_coord_value(int const value, int const x_y,
        int *y, int *x)
{
    static t_coord          coord_dest[SIZE_file_MAX * SIZE_file_MAX];
    static int              loop = 0;

    if (y == NULL || x == NULL || value >= SIZE_file_MAX * SIZE_file_MAX)
        return (-1);
    if (loop == 0)
    {
        for((*y) = 0; (*y) < x_y; (*y)++)
            for (*x = 0; *x < x_y; (*x)++)
                if (x_y == 3)
                {
                    coord_dest[g_grid_3x3[*y][*x]].y = (*y);
                    coord_dest[g_grid_3x3[*y][*x]].x = (*x);
                }
                else if (x_y == 4)
                {
                    coord_dest[g_grid_4x4[*y][*x]].y = (*y);
                    coord_dest[g_grid_4x4[*y][*x]].x = (*x);
                }
                else if (x_y == 5)
                {
                    coord_dest[g_grid_5x5[*y][*x]].y = (*y);
                    coord_dest[g_grid_5x5[*y][*x]].x = (*x);
                }
        loop = 1;
    }
    (*y) = coord_dest[value].y;
    (*x) = coord_dest[value].x;
    return (true);
}
```

Thx a lot for your help I am stack for more than one week LOL.